# Location of espresso test reports into files created dynamically

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso, dynamic-reports, test-reporting

Currently, all my test reports are being created and stored in the folder 'test-reports' in the project root directory. Below is the gradle file, in which I have specified the directory under 'testOptions'.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.edk1kor.decodedemov3"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testOptions{
        reportDir "$rootDir/test-reports"
    }
}
```

I want to create a new folder, each time a test is run. Is it possible to dynamically create a folder each time? If not via gradle code, via the android source code?